# unable to use preinstalled python packages in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

guys,

here's the problem. I have got access to a server with jupyter notebook. There are already several packages installed on this server, which I want to use. But unfortunately it doesn't work with all packages. E.g. pandas, numpy and others work but I have problems with sklearn and Tensorflow.
When I query the list of all installed packages via pip I see for example the installation of Tensorflow:

[image]

If I want to import the package I receive this message:

[image]

It's the same with sklearn. Other packages work. Since there are still several people working on this server I wouldn't like to reinstall packages or restart the server. Does anybody have an idea where my mistake is?

Thanks a lot and stay healthy!

Comment: The usual way to manage packages for a project is to create a virtual environment in which you install everything you need, including jupyter, tensorflow, pandas etc.
pipenv is arguably the best tool for this. https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/ but there are others.

This way you can have a coherent reproducible set of packages and you can install whatever versions of whatever you want and not be dependent on what happens to already be lying around.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple versions of Python installed on the server.
And the version that `pip` is using does not have to be the same version as your notebook is running.

So first, check which version of Python your notebook is using; Open the `File` menu and click on `New console for notebook`. In the console you should see the Python version. Say it shows this:

> Python 3.7.6

Then call `python3.7 -m pip list` to see which modules are actually installed for that version of Python.

**Edit**

> Is there an easy way to tell only my juptyer notebook to take this version?

Use `Change Kernel...` from the `Kernel` menu.

Comment: okay, you're right. My Python3 jupyter notebook runs with python 2.7.17. 
according to the ''jupyter kernelspec list'' there is also a Python3 version installed:
/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3

Is there an easy way to tell only my juptyer notebook to take this version?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I already did that -> but my python version is still 2.7.17

Comment: After the change, restart the kernel.

Comment: Then ik looks like the `python3` kernel is not working. Contact the system administrator.